# Adding security to my workbook internally using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For testing purposes lets assume the code to unlock the workbook is 1.
I want an input box to show up on opening, if the user puts in an incorrect code/Or selects cancel on the input box then the workbook closes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

 Code = Application.InputBox("Enter School Code", CancelCode)

    If Code < 0 > 1 Or False Then
    Code = Int(1)
        MsgBox ("Unrecognised Code")

Application.Workbooks("CODING.xlsm").Close 'False

    End If

End Sub
```

At the moment it appears but runs if any number is entered and also closes the input box and allows access if cancel is clicked.

Comment: Your `If Code < 0 > 1 Or False Then` is wrong (it is valid syntax but probably don't do what you think it will). You have to repeat Code each time like in `Ìf Code < 0 Or Code > 1 Or Code = False Then`. And why didn't you simply check Code angaist the good value like `If Code <> 1 Then`?

Comment: Vincent, what confuses me is whilst using the syntax If Code < 0 > 1 Or False Then  i had it working for a period of time until a deletion occurred and had to re do the code, i tried the <>1 but again it accepted any number put in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Code As Variant
    Code = Application.InputBox("Enter School Code", CancelCode)
    If Not Code = 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Unrecognised Code")
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Just tested it and it works for me.

I should add, however, that this is extremely low-level security, which could be bypassed by anyone with even rudimentary knowledge of VBA. You simply have to set *Application.EnableEvents = False* in another workbook (or in the VBA Immediate window) before opening up your workbook, and the Workbook_Open event will not run at all.

Comment: You can also just hold the shift button whilst opening the workbook to disable any auto-open code from running.

Comment: @chris That works perfectly thank you. i know it is very basic although it isnt strictly being used as a security feature it is more of a tool to personalise the workbook as i plan to have different codes for different people which then trigger other macros off. i just needed to get the fundamental part correct, many thanks

Comment: Matthew, you're welcome. A suggestion though: if you want different people to see different things, you could use the variable `Environ("UserName")`. For example
`Select Case Environ("UserName") /
Case "Matthew Bond" /
    Msgbox "Owner of this document" /
Case "Joe Bloggs" /
    Msgbox "Someone else" /
End Select`
(/ characters representing line breaks)